# Yii2 model rule blacklist words array check

Tags: yii2

I tried **yii2-word-validator** but it doesn't work with cyrillic...
I need validarion rule like:

```
[['header', 'description'], WordValidator::className(), 'blacklist' => ['Кириллица', 'Other word']],
```

Comment: It looks like there is `u` regex flag missing in this validator's code, so it won't work with UTF-8 characters. You could report this to the author or prepare PR there fixing it.

Comment: I have reported this issue to plugin author